# How to parse basic XML data which has one tag

Tags: go, xml-parsing

I can parse complex XML results but I fail at this simple thing which is api returning simple answers like this

```
 xmlFile := <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><TOKEN>C5F3DCFE370047ECAA9120F4E305B7D2</TOKEN>
```

I can't parse TOKEN. I tried everything but can't figure out. I'm using this syntax:

```
s := strings.Split(string(result),">")
    s = strings.Split(s[2],"<")
    b.Token = s[0]
```

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><TOKEN>C5F3DCFE370047ECAA9120F4E305B7D2</TOKEN>` how to parse this (also api returns `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><ERROR>a error </ERROR>` informations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unmarshaling separate top-level elements you can implement a custom [unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.17.2#Unmarshaler).

```golang
type Response struct {
    Token string
    Error string
}

func (r *Response) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    switch start.Name.Local {
    case "TOKEN":
        if err := d.DecodeElement(&r.Token, &start); err !=nil {
            return err
        }
    case "ERROR":
        if err := d.DecodeElement(&r.Error, &start); err !=nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OQy4ShS_vFx

Comment: Thank you for your sample code and answer to  guide me sir, your solution is much more better in real project.